# How to pass a jquery variable as a url parameter inside an ajax call of a fancybox function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the $.fancybox() function in my application using jquery and Spring MVC. I have the following function using which I am trying to open a model window using fancybox to show some data as popup.

```
$(document).on('click', '#versionBtn' ,function (event){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    webContentId = $(".selected").closest("div").attr("id");
    console.log('The selected webContentId  : '+webContentId );
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $.fancybox({
        type: 'ajax',
        href : '${rc.getContextPath()}/module/simplewebcontent/list-webcontent-versions?webContentDefinitionId=webContentId',
        autoSize : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        closeBtn : true,
        fitToView : true,
        autoCenter : true               
    });     

});
```

Now when the click function is called, the value of variable `webContentId` is not getting set in the url.
Is there any way I can get the value of that variable in the url ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add (concatenate) this value to address string and it will be sent to server as a GET request

```
href : '${rc.getContextPath()}/module/simplewebcontent/list-webcontent-versions?webContentDefinitionId=' + webContentId,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
$.fancybox({
    type: 'ajax',
    href : '${rc.getContextPath()}/module/simplewebcontent/list-webcontent-versions?webContentDefinitionId='+webContentId,
    autoSize : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    closeBtn : true,
    fitToView : true,
    autoCenter : true               
});
```

You want the value of the javascript variable webContentId to be passed in the url, not  the string 'webContentId'

Good luck with this

Answer (score 0):

The basic solution is the same as in the other answers, but I prefer this method, especially with multiple parameters:

```
$.fancybox({
    type: 'ajax',
    href:  '${rc.getContextPath()}/module/simplewebcontent/list-webcontent-versions?' + $.param({
        webContentDefinitionId: webContentId 
    }),
    autoSize : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    closeBtn : true,
    fitToView : true,
    autoCenter : true
});
```

The jQuery `param` function does the neccessary escaping for you, if it is needed (now, this is not the case).